# @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) generate int column instead of varchar

Tags: enums, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using spring jpa with hibernate and ms Sqlserver. I've an entity with an enum property with an `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation. When database schema is generated, the column filled with enum value has an int type instead of a char type.

Bean methods to set  database properties:

```
private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");

    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create-drop");       
    properties.setProperty("ejb.naming_strategy","layer.controller.configuration.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider","filesystem");


    return properties;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);        
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("layer.domain","layer.application.security.authentication.entities");
    factory.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory;
}
```

enum and entity:

```
public enum Elenco {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="elenco")
public class ElencoClass extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name="nomeECognome")
    private String nome;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar")
    private Elenco ele;


    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Override
    protected Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setId(Long id) {

        super.id=id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Elenco getEle() {
        return ele;
    }

    public void setEle(Elenco ele) {
        this.ele = ele;
    }
}
```

This is the table generated by spring:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[elenco](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ele] [int] NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](255) NULL,
```

Comment: Did you try to put the annotation to getter method instead of the field?

Comment: Thank you for replay. Yes, I do but nothing change.

Comment: one more point, why are you providing column type in `columnDefinition` whereas you are specifying the data type by using `EnumType.STRING` as `columnDefinition` overrides the DDL.

Comment: I try without columnDefinition but the issue is not solved.

Comment: Same here, without columnDefinition="VARCHAR" the code just breaks because Hibernate insists on BIGINT, despite  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

Answer (score 0):

If you can write  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) on getter method, that will works.

Comment: Had to add columnDefinition = "VARCHAR" to make hibernate stop complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? You still need to have @Column annotation that specify the column name but not column definition in the get method.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="ele")
public Elenco getEle() {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@Column(name = "ele", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "enum('ELE1', 'ELE2')")
```